# How to create one nodejs API with two differents databases?

Tags: node.js, typescript, api

We plan to create one API backend nodejs typescript application for 2 differents customers. One customer use mysql (customerM) and other one use elasticsearch (customerE).

When customerM connect to the app, we want our API use mysql and if customerE connect, we want our API use ES.

We know that NoSQL and MySQL have differents approach but We want one backend for code maintenance reasons (having two seperate projects that do the same thing is not a good solution)

For now i'm playing with architecture and retrieve data from mysql and from json file to simulate the clients. I use routes => controllers => services => models. We want to retrieve data from models, transform it and send it to the service (the service will always have same schema). For now, i have sensors.model.ts who is responsible to choose the right model to use from an env variable:

```
let Sensor = null;

switch (config.db.source) {
  case 'file':
    Sensor = require('./sensors.model.file');
    break;
  case 'mysql':
    Sensor = require('./sensors.model.mysql');
    break;
}

export default Sensor;
```

In each files sensors.model.xxx.ts i have a find method but with different code. My service just use the find method, my models send the result with the same format.

But i don't like this approach. Do you have some advices, ressources, ... ?

I'm new to data layer, DDD, ...

Comment: Hi nathansolo. The question is a bit vague and so it's difficult to give advice without more information. In general, dynamic `require` is something I would advise against, especially when using Typescript.

Comment: @cdimitroulas i edit my question and change client for customer. More understandable i think.